# Warning : "Sending 'NSObject *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSCopying>'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdictionary, nscopying

I am struck in this warning for many hours... Am getting

The code is,

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*)iOSDiction
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *tmpDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[m_coordDic count]];
            for (NSObject *key in [m_coordDic allKeys]) 
            {
                [tmpDic setObject:[m_coordDic objectForKey:key] forKey:key];  //Warning
            }
            return tmpDic;
        }
```

**Warning :**

> "Sending 'NSObject *' to parameter of incompatible type
>   'id'

Passing argument to parameter `aKey` here

```
NSDictionary.h

- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id <NSCopying>)aKey;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSDictionary` keys should conform to `NSCopying` protocol. It is a basic requirement of a key as specified in the [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference. In general, `NSObject` does not conform to the protocol(its subclasses might), so you are getting a warning. The correct way to do this is

```
NSMutableDictionary *tmpDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[m_coordDic count]];
for (NSObject<NSCopying> *key in [m_coordDic allKeys]) 
{
    [tmpDic setObject:[m_coordDic objectForKey:key] forKey:key];  //Warning
}
return tmpDic;
```

This ensures your key is any object confirming to `NSCopying` protocol.

EDIT: It seems what you are really trying to do is simply `[m_coordDic mutableCopy]`, a shallow copy. Any reason you are not doing this?

Answer (score 3):

NSObject doesn't conform to NSCopying. By typing the variable as NSObject, you're telling the compiler to make sure that any messages you send through that variable are responded to by NSObject. Since NSObject doesn't conform to NSCopying, you get that error message.

If you're trying to tell the compiler that a variable is some kind of object, but never mind the type, you should type it as `id`. So:

```
for (id key in m_coordDic)
```

(BTW, you don't need the allKeys. Fast enumeration already enumerates keys.)

Comment: Ideally you want `for (id<NSCopying> in ...)`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Maybe it's just my bedtime, but why is that more ideal? I can't see how it would ever make any difference.

Comment: Personally I find it a little bit more self-documenting. It clarifies the need of the key.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the **incompatible Assignment**. So you should use `Particular object type` Or `id--> for any instances of object.`

Try this :

```
 for (id key in [arr allKeys])
    {
        [tmpDic setObject:[m_coordDic objectForKey:key] forKey:key];  //Warning
    }
```

Comment: I downvoted initially because the original answer was wrong (something about how you shouldn't pass a pointer). Then you edited and I tried to remove the downvote but SO isn't letting me.

Comment: @Chuck Thanks, Yes, it was wrong with my assumption(Explanation). So i removed that part only . AnyHow thanks for your propose.

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary keys must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.  That's what `id<NSCopying>` means.

Clearly, you are already working with NSDictionary keys that do conform to `NSCopying`, but you've declared your `key` variable as `NSObject*`, which by itself does not conform to `NSCopying`.

You need to declare that `key` does conform to `NSCopying`.  You can do that with `NSObject<NSCopying>* key`; however, many people would use `id` instead.

`id` is a special type that tells the compiler to skip any type checking.  In a simple case like this, using `id` is usually fine:

```
for (id key in [myDictionary allKeys])
{
    // etc...
}
```